# C# Aforge Library and Saving Bitmap Resolution?

Tags: c#, image, aforge

I write an exmaple into c# using Aforge Latest version on [This link](http://www.aforgenet.com). We know:

```
static void video_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame;
        bitmap.Save(@"c:\\picture.jpg");
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    bool finish = false ;
    VideoCaptureDevice videoSource = new VideoCaptureDevice( videoDevices[0].MonikerString );
    videoSource.NewFrame += new NewFrameEventHandler( video_NewFrame );
}
```

Can save a frame on PC as a picture (there is no limitation on picture format). My problem is about how we can configure that 1024*768 bitmap saved on my PC? or Full HD picture be saved?

Comment: Note that `Bitmap.Save` defaults to png format, not jpeg. Also, if this is a command line app it'll probably finish right after assigning that event handler, and will never wait for anything to happen. Honestly not sure how to handle events like that in a command line app.

Comment: I have no idea what you're actually _asking_ though... are you asking how to resize an image? Or how to request specific formats from the `VideoCaptureDevice`?

Comment: @Nyerguds I'm so sorry for my complex question. I need to capture HD from video capture device and then save a picture with HD dimension

Comment: [According to the manual](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/4fe99ff3-ac67-3ac1-d554-00b13113362f.htm), that `eventArgs.Frame` is already `Bitmap` class, so no need to cast it, but besides that note on png I gave, that should be okay. What is your actual problem? Did you try this code? Did it do what you expected? I do notice this code never actually [calls `videoSource.Start()`](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/f4d3c2ba-605c-f066-f969-68260ce5e141.htm).

Comment: @Nyerguds my problem is in two part 1) how I can configure web cam resolution to config HD? and How I can save different resolution as snapshot?

Comment: @Nyerguds How I can share code with you?

Comment: No. If you want people to see more code to help solve your problem, you **edit your question and put it in there.** As for the rest, I'm not familiar with the AForge `VideoCaptureDevice` class, but there should be plenty of examples here on SO on how to resize bitmaps of the `System.Drawing.Bitmap` class.